# Problemas ao tentar alterar um text view do nav_header_main.xml

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estou trabalhando pela primeira vez com o Navigation Drawer Activity, e gostaria de mudar (pelo java) o texto que aparece no menu nav_header_main.xml

[image: Em vermelho é o texto que quero alterar]

Em vermelho é o texto que quero alterar.

Abaixo está o xml gerado automaticamente pelo android studio, eu só adicionei um ID para este TextView:

```
TextView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
   android:text="Android Studio"
   android:id="@+id/txtUsuarioLogado"
   android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
```

Então, no onCreate da classe MainActivity.java eu fiz os seguintes códigos:

```
   TextView txtUsuarioLogado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUsuarioLogado);

   txtUsuarioLogado.setText("Nome Alterado");
```

Porém, o TextView está ficando sempre com valor nulo, travando a aplicação. Como seria a forma correta de manipula-lo

Answer (score 2):

Partindo do princípio de que o travamento que você se refere é um `NullPointerException`, o método `findViewById` não está encontrando o ID que você informou. Isso acontece porque o id informado não pertence à hierarquia do layout pesquisado. Logo, o `txtUsuarioLogado` não deve estar no mesmo nível que o layout da activity.

Sugiro verificar os layouts e estruturá-los da seguinte maneira:

**main_activity.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/main_activity" <--- o layout de conteúdo da activity
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/menu_header" <--- o layout do cabeçalho
        app:menu="@menu/menu_sidebar" <--- as opções do menu
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    // Obtém a referência do layout de navegação
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    // Obtém a referência da view de cabeçalho
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    // Obtém a referência do nome do usuário e altera seu nome
    TextView txtUsuarioLogado = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtUsuarioLogado);
    txtUsuarioLogado.setText("Nome Alterado");   
}
```