# problemas em passar dados para nova activity

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-activity

Estou com dificuldade quando passo um dado utilizando o put.Extras.

Meu aplicativo está dando crash e não consigo identificar o motivo.

Ele não está conseguindo passar os dados de uma activity para outra.

Activity que envia os dados:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    edtNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);
    edtPhoneField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
    edtCompanySettings = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCompanySettings);
    edtEmailSettings = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmailSettings);
    pd = new SpotsDialog(this, R.style.CustomPD);

    imgProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfileImage);

    btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    btnConfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mCustomerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userID);

    getUserInfo();

    imgProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });

    btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pd.show();
            saveUserInformation();
            //enviarDados();
            enviarDadosShare();
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Os dados foram salvos!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
    });
}

public void enviarDadosShare(){
    Intent enviarDados = new Intent(this, TelaPrincipalActivity.class);
    EditText nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);
    SharedPreferences prefs =  getSharedPreferences("preferencias",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor ed =  prefs.edit();
    ed.putString("nome",  nome.getText().toString());
    ed.apply();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gravado  com  sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    enviarDados.putExtra("nome", nome.getText().toString());
    startActivity(enviarDados);
}
```

Estou tentando passar os dados para meu menu lateral

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é meu método para receber os dados da outra activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_principal);

        inicializarComponentes();
        inicializarFirebase();
        eventoEdit();
    receberDadosSahred();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}

public void receberDadosSahred(){
    Intent intent2 = getIntent();

    if (intent2 != null){
        Bundle params = intent2.getExtras();

        if (params != null){
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

            String str = intent2.getStringExtra("nome");

            textView.setText(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Em modo de debug:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro que está apresentando:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: homologa.cappta.com.br.capptahomologa, PID: 12973
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{homologa.cappta.com.br.capptahomologa/homologa.cappta.com.br.capptahomologa.Activity.TelaPrincipalActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2830)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>                         at homologa.cappta.com.br.capptahomologa.Activity.TelaPrincipalActivity.receberDadosSahred(TelaPrincipalActivity.java:118)
>                         at homologa.cappta.com.br.capptahomologa.Activity.TelaPrincipalActivity.onCreate(TelaPrincipalActivity.java:91)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6984)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1235)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2783)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769) 
>   E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{homologa.cappta.com.br.capptahomologa/homologa.cappta.com.br.capptahomologa.Activity.TelaPrincipalActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2830)
>                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909)
>                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606)
>                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592)
>                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
>                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>                            at homologa.cappta.com.br.capptahomologa.Activity.TelaPrincipalActivity.receberDadosSahred(TelaPrincipalActivity.java:118)
>                            at homologa.cappta.com.br.capptahomologa.Activity.TelaPrincipalActivity.onCreate(TelaPrincipalActivity.java:91)
>                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6984)
>                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1235)
>                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2783)
>                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909) 
>                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606) 
>                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592) 
>                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769) 
>   Application terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução..

Esqueci de referenciar o layout NavigationView. 
[Problemas ao tentar alterar um text view do nav_header_main.xml](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256028/problemas-ao-tentar-alterar-um-text-view-do-nav-header-main-xml)

Answer (score 1):

O erro está na declaração:

```
TextView nomeView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailPrincipal);
```

Ele é um TextView, porém depois do = você está colocando (EditText).

Não tem nada haver com o Bundle ou o Intent.

Comment: Fiz a mudança, mas mesmo assim continua dando crash no app :(

Comment: O mesmo erro? Tem ctz? Da uma olhada no LogCat se o erro é o mesmo

Comment: `TextView nomeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailPrincipal);`

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei algumas divergências no print do seu debug e a mensagem de erro e o código enviado.

Primeiramente, certifique, se corrigiu o cast para o `TextView`, declarado como *nomeView*. Conforme resposta do Leonardo Dias.

Em seguida, a própria mensagem de erro,  já que o erro diz `cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText at`. Indicando a própria falha no Casting.

*Nota: Atualize o seu projeto e o Android Studio, pois este casting é redundante a partir da API 26. Facilitando a leitura, reduzindo e evitando erros no código*

Depois, no print do seu debug, o parâmetro *params* recebido pela intent. Está recebendo a chave "nome", diferente que está no código `String email = params.getString("email");`.

Para finalizar, confirme se o id está correto, pois no print está `id.txtNomePrinc` e o no código está `id.emailPrincipal`. Já que mesmo depois da declaração da variável TextView chamada *nomeView* , continua nula, conforme o seu debug.

Comment: Rodrigo, estou tentando trazer a informação na minha nav_header (onNavigationItemSelected) e acredito que por algum motivo ele não consegue encontrar o id da minha textview. 
Adicionei uma foto de onde estou tentando trazer a informação.

Comment: Isso só é um problema, se vc não está trazendo o layout através do `setContentView(R.layout.nav_header_tela_principal);` Está é a activity que vc está utilizando? Os apontamentos que eu mencionei, vc analisou?

Comment: Analisei sim os apontamentos, fiz as alterações e mesmo assim continua o erro. 
A activity que estou utilizando é setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_principal);
Será se eu tenho que criar uma nova activity e chamar essa setContentView(R.layout.nav_header_tela_principal); ?

Comment: Se for um menu de aba lateral, vc não precisa criar uma activity para ele. Mas eu tenho o costume de inserir o layout do navigation na minha própria main_activity. Não sei, exatamente, como vc está fazendo.

Comment: é um menu lateral. 
O meu está assim:
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_principal);

            inicializarComponentes();
            inicializarFirebase();
            eventoEdit();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawe
    
    }

Comment: Consegue Editar a sua pergunta, com esta parte? Já com a alteração de como seu código está no momento? Se puder, altere a mensagem de erro que vc está recebendo, na classe onde vc está com erro?

Comment: Editei minha pergunta com as alterações, estou usando a API 27 em meu projeto.